# Curve_fit to apply_along_axis. How to speed it up?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I've got some big datasets to which I'd like to fit monoexponential time decays.

The data consists of multiple 4D datasets, acquired at different times, and the fit should thus run along a 5th dimension (through datasets).

The code I'm currently using is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

[... load 4D datasets ....]
data = (dataset1, dataset2, dataset3)
times = (10, 20, 30)

def monoexponential(t, M0, t_const):
    return M0*np.exp(-t/t_const)

# Starting guesses to initiate  descent.
M0_init = 80.0
t_const_init = 50.0
init_guess = (M0_init, t_const_init)

def fit(vector):
    try:
        nlfit, nlpcov = opt.curve_fit(monoexponential, times, vector,
                                      p0=init_guess,
                                      sigma=None,
                                      check_finite=False,
                                      maxfev=100, ftol=0.5, xtol=1,
                                      bounds=([0, 2000], [0, 800]))
        M0, t_const = nlfit
    except:
        t_const = 0

    return t_const

# Concatenate datasets in data into a single 5D array.
concat5D = np.concatenate([block[..., np.newaxis] for block in data],
                     axis=len(data[0].shape))

# And apply the curve fitting along the last dimension.
decay_map = np.apply_along_axis(fit, len(concat5D.shape) - 1, concat5D)
```

The code works fine, but takes forever (e.g, for `dataset1.shape == (100,100,50,500)`). I've read some other topics mentioning that `apply_along_axis` is very slow, so I'm guessing that's the culprit. Unfortunately, I don't really know what could be used as an alternative here (except maybe an explicit for loop?).

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to avoid `apply_along_axis` and speed up curve_fit being called multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

So you are applying a `fit` operation 100*100*50*500 times, to a 1d array (of 3 values in the example, more in real life?)?

`apply_along_axis` does iterate over all the dimensions of the input array, except for one.  There's no compiling or doing this `fit` over multiple axes at once.

Without `apply_along_axis` the easiest approach is to reshape the array into a 2d one, compressing (100,100,50,500) to one (250...,) dimension, and then iterating on that.  And then reshaping the result.

I was thinking that concatenating the `datasets` on a last axis might be slower than doing so on the first, but timings suggest otherwise.

`np.stack` is a new version of `concatenate` that makes it easy to add the new axis any where.

```
In [319]: x=np.ones((2,3,4,5),int)
In [320]: d=[x,x,x,x,x,x]

In [321]: np.stack(d,axis=0).shape   # same as np.array(d)
Out[321]: (6, 2, 3, 4, 5)

In [322]: np.stack(d,axis=-1).shape
Out[322]: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

for a larger list (with a trivial `sum` function):

```
In [295]: d1=[x]*1000       # make a big list

In [296]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(sum,-1,np.stack(d1,-1)).shape
10 loops, best of 3: 39.7 ms per loop

In [297]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(sum,0,np.stack(d1,0)).shape
10 loops, best of 3: 39.2 ms per loop
```

an explicit loop using array reshape times about the same

```
In [312]: %%timeit 
   .....: d2=np.stack(d1,-1)
   .....: d2=d2.reshape(-1,1000)
   .....: res=np.stack([sum(i) for i in d2],0).reshape(d1[0].shape)
   .....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 39.1 ms per loop
```

But a function like `sum` can work on whole array, and do so much faster

```
In [315]: timeit np.stack(d1,-1).sum(-1).shape
100 loops, best of 3: 3.52 ms per loop
```

So changing the stacking and iteration methods doesn't make much difference in speed.  But changing the 'fit' so it can work over more than one dimension can be a big help.  I don't know enough of `optimize.fit` to  know if that is possible.

====================

I just dug into the code for `apply_along_axis`.  It basically constructs an index that looks like `ind=(0,1,slice(None),2,1)`, and does `func(arr[ind])`, and then increments it, sort like long arithmetic with carry. So it is just systematically stepping through all elements, while keeping one axis a `:` slice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've looked into scipy's `curve_fit` and `least_squares` code. I found out that there are thousands of (in my case unnecessary) checks, function calls and helper variable assignments that probably account for a huge overhead when calling the functions multiple times. I guess the best thing to do here is to write my own function to call the solver `trf_no_bounds` directly.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, where you're fitting a single exponential, you're likely better off to take the log of your data. Then fitting becomes linear and *that* is much faster than a nonlinear least squares, and can likely be vectorized since it becomes pretty much a linear algebra problem.

(And of course, if you have an idea of how to improve `least_squares`, that might be appreciated by the scipy devs.)